# Blank page of next website url in selenium chrome driver

Tags: java, selenium

I am automating  https://www.cleartrip.com/ website using java in selenium framework. After filling all the form details, when the selenium clicks on "searchBtn" button, then a blank page loads with the next page url. It remains blank every time I refresh. But if I copy paste the final website in my chrome browser then the results is showing. And this is happening in both firefox and chrome driver.

I have added a picture also. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZHPG.png
Can anyone tell me where am I taking the wrong step?
Thanks..

My code is below:

```
public void formFilling() throws Exception {

        driver.findElement(By.id("OneWay")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("FromTag")).sendKeys("Delhi");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Del') and contains(text(), 'Indira')]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("ToTag")).sendKeys("Hyderabad");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Hyd') and contains(text(), 'Rajiv')]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("DepartDate")).sendKeys("Fri, 16 Apr,2021");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title=\"More search options\"]")).click();
        Select s = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("Class")));
        s.selectByVisibleText("Economy");
        driver.findElement(By.id("SearchBtn")).submit();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[7]/div[1]/div[3]/a/span")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[8]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
        ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZHPG.png
```

Comment: Make sure the website (or any security layer) does not block webcrawlers.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just too fast. You enter all the values, then you click on the search button and immediately your try to take a screenshot.

After clicking on "save changes" or "submit" buttons you need to give the browser time to refresh the data and load the updated page:

In your case do this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("SearchBtn")).submit();
Thread.Sleep(5000);
// continue your test
```

If 5 seconds wait is not enough - rise it up.

Comment: It doesn't work. I have tried everything and then put the question here.

Comment: @User3323334 change the line where you do submit() to click(). You just need to mimic mouse or keyboard clicks using Selenium. Also, try to set driver only once (no need to do it 3 times) and set the timeout to 100 or 200. Tell me how this worked for you.